# Performing only update of latest code from svn through maven 3

Tags: java, svn, maven-3

I have downloaded some code from svn into my system. Now through maven I need to check if there are any updates on this code and if so then update it. I need not do a checkout of the whole code. So is it possible to do just update the existing source code of any project without maven creating a checkout directory?

I followed this post: [Settings for Maven for conditional checkout or update from SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817229/settings-for-maven-for-conditional-checkout-or-update-from-svn).

However I think only update won't work if I don't check out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  You can manually call `mvn scm:update`, which will update the sources, if there are any changes, based on the `<scm>` settings that is specified for the project in the pom. Refer to [this usage page](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html) and [advanced scm commands](http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/examples/scm-advance-features.html) documentation.

The other way is to invoke this goal as part of the standard maven lifecycle.  This is what is attempted in the [referred question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817229/settings-for-maven-for-conditional-checkout-or-update-from-svn).  There is no reason why update alone will not work. You can use the code snippet for the `update-project` `<execution>` and modify it to your need.

The latter may not be suited since build will not happen if you do off-line builds or if there is no scm connectivity for some reason.  It is arguably better to do `mvn scm:update clean install` or something similar.

Comment: thanks a lot Raghuram .. i used the command method and its working fine..Also if i do need to checkout the code too then do i need to do mvn scm:co clean install ?

Comment: also if i do through the pom.xml then what should i write for the <basedir> ? so that it does not look for code under target but instead project/src ? In the link mentioned it is project.build.directory so it looks for checkout code under target and since its not there it gives error that the target does not exist

Comment: i did manage to get the solution by specifying ./src as the <baseDir> but still i think some property can be used there..Also using the setting in pom.xml can we disable update through command line while taking a build ?